# Reactor GroupedFlux performance depends on side-effect

Tags: group-by, project-reactor, side-effects

The following code executes 3 time faster when the `doOnNext(...)` side-effect is not commented out:

```
@Test
void groupByFluxAggregateLoadTest() {
    int numberOfGroups = 30_000;
    Flux
            .range(0, numberOfGroups * 10)
            .groupBy(i -> i % numberOfGroups)
            .flatMap(
                integerIntegerGroupedFlux -> integerIntegerGroupedFlux
                    .count()
                    //.doOnNext(n -> {})
                ,
                numberOfGroups + 1
            )
            .as(StepVerifier::create)
            .expectNextCount(numberOfGroups)
            .verifyComplete();
}
```

Does anyone understand that?

Comment: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/3239